# How to make in CSV First and Last name in one

Tags: powershell, csv

I have one CSV that looks like this:

```
Versand Vorname;Versand-Nachname;Versand-Zusatz;Versand-Firma;Versand
Thomas         ;Lellig          ;              ;             ;Brunnenstrasse
```

I want to edit it to look like this:

```
Versand Vorname;Versand-Nachname ;Versand-Zusatz;Versand-Firma;Versand
Thomas Lellig  ;                 ;              ;             ;Brunnenstrasse
```

So I need to merge the first and last names, using PowerShell.

Here's a picture of my source CSV and what the edited CSV should look like:

[image: Source CSV File]

[image: Edited CSV File]

Comment: Your example line 0 seems identical, so it's unclear what you are trying to do. Give better transformation rules.

Comment: @harrymc i believe line 0 is the headers

Answer (score 1):

Here in a little bit less code:

You need to read the CSV, combine first- and surname, empty the surname column, return the modified object, and export it again.

```
$SourcePath = "C:\Install\testabc.csv"
$DestinationPath = "C:\Install\testbcd.csv"

Import-Csv $SourcePath -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object {
    $_."Versand Vorname" = "{0} {1}" -f $_."Versand Vorname", $_."Versand-Nachname"
    $_."Versand-Nachname" = ""
    $_
} | Export-Csv $DestinationPath -NoTypeInformation -Force -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

if you want this without the quotes - what I would not suggest [because some fields need the quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules), you can use the following:

if you are on PowerShell 7+ you can just add `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` to `Export-CSV`

if you are on PowerShell 6 and lower, you can replace them after you created the new file, just add these lines to the script:

```
$File = Get-Content $DestinationPath -Encoding UTF8
$File -replace '"','' | Out-File $DestinationPath -Encoding utf8 -Force
```

However, I would not recommend to replace the quotes

Comment: i have this output, something i wrong : Import-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argume
nt that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:12
+ Import-Csv $FilePath -Delimiter ";" | ForEach-Object {
+            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvComm 
   and

Comment: Hey thane you  this is what i look for. i have found the mistake $FilePath must be $SourcePath thank you thank you

Comment: @Drago oh yes :-). Sorry for that. changed it in my answer

Comment: Hi SimonS  one more thing i need unicod for German Lenguage you know there is some like this ä ö ü ß  how to set it

Comment: @Drago I added UTF8 support (-Encoding Parameter)

Comment: hi SimonS, it is onother problem  so the files is generated and it is not with the same name so $SourcePath = "C:\Install\testabc.csv"  will not work for me so how can i take the file that is in direcrtory it is only one file. thank you

Comment: @Drago if there's always only one file in this directory, use `$SourcePath = Get-ChildItem C:\FilePath\xy -Filter *.csv -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Comment: thank you   thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

No powershell, but maybe you have [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) at hand?

In case you have:

- open your CSV with NP++
- press [Strg]+[H] to open the replace dialog window
- in the lower-left corner, set the mode to regular expression
- search for: `^([^;]+);` (exactly this pattern!)
- replace with: `$1`
- click button "replace all"

Works for me, might help you too :)

Comment: Hi thank you but i need to do this in powershell  or with other script because i upload this file and process must me automatic, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after

Ive got the import and export in my C:\Temp folder just change for your use case

```
$objs =@();
$output = Import-csv -Path C:\Temp\test.csv -Delimiter “;”| ForEach { 
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
        'Versand Vorname'  = [String]::Concat($_.'Versand Vorname',' ',$_.'Versand-Nachname')
        'Versand-Nachname' = ''
        'Versand-Zusatz'  = $_.'Versand-Zusatz'   
        'Versand-Firma' = $_.'Versand-Firma'
        'Versand' = $_.'Versand'         
    }   
    $objs += $Object;
} 
$objs 
$objs | Export-CSv  C:\Temp\temp.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter “;”
```

[image]

Comment: hi thank you  but i thing that i make something wrong
i have this output #TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Versand-Zusatz","FullName","Versand-Firma","Versand"
,"",,

Comment: @Drago see update.

Comment: no not work for me, how can i share you  my csv file ?

Comment: hi i have fix it now work and for me. just a little problem i need space between first and last name in original file  is like this Thomas;Lellig;;;Brunnenstrasse , when i make your script  output is ThomasLelling

Comment: super thank you  only last thing in output file make it with "" and with Delimiter , if possible to not has "" and Delimiter ;

Comment: @Drago delimiter can only be one character see edited post

Comment: Hi i have replaced with Delimiter ";", but how can i remove the "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103646/discussion-between-drago-and-sqltemp).